# Calculating magnetic flux explicitly for alternating current generator

Tags: electromagnetism

So I know $$\iint_S \mathbf{B} . d\mathbf{S}$$ is the magnetic flux. I know that the answer is $BA \cos (\omega t)$ because it's a little 'obvious', but I like to be able to do it mathematically too and generate the 'cos' term directly from the integral.

Any help would be appreciate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I don't think the cos term is generated mathematically. It is generated vectorly.The flux is defined as the number of field lines passing through a given area.That gives flux as $B.A$ in vector form. And in dot product we know $B.A=|B||A|cos\omega t$ Hence the cos comes from here.

Comment: And for a non-rotating coil, you simply set w = 0 to get BA?

Comment: No, there we have to check the angle between B vector and A vector.